# UWP Overlay over other apps

Tags: c#, xaml, overlay, uwp

Does anyone know how to make overlays in UWP? Like the one in the Windows Feedback app for Windows Mobile.

[Overlay from Feedback app](https://sxdpza.bn1301.livefilestore.com/y3p515n7aY1jjyvr4UEL2uXk40Xb0dQBSuAicDHvWMrZwW6gkqGjeAPPQSdAxUKuQ1HzUxeGhGzIwNgESGMS6rqWwu585EOTkFz5e3p1O4owS99ApqBJdLfvWAJrR0Xy6cjR1HcpnRODyuiOVOHTDpaYUThOIY_GL6Z_svXwJXBzPs/wp_ss_20160521_0001%20%5B261119%5D.png)
to see for yourself go to the feedback app, select new feedback and then the camera icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vote for this new feature to be included in future Windows 10 Builds [on uservoice](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/11179821-uwp-windows-always-on-top)

Comment: But if the feedback app can do it why can't we do it?

Comment: You should file in the Feedback Hub as well. The Feedback Hub itself can use additional APIs not allowed for normal Store apps.